# PHP download file: show progress in browser

Tags: php, progress-bar, download

User on my site can download files. Sometimes these files are pretty large and I would like users to see download progress bar at their browsers.

I use the following code to give user a file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fullFileName));
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");

$fileHandler = fopen($fullFileName, 'r');
while(!feof($fileHandler)){
    echo fread($fileHandler, 2048);
}
fclose($fileHandler);
```

When I run this script browser(FireFox) freezes for some time, I can see loading colour circle and only after save/open dialog file appears. When I click on "save" button, file almost immediately is downloaded to my computer(while file is quite large - 50 Mb).

I want to have downloading system like on this [site](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso). Dialog for save/opean appears immediately when you click on any links. And after you can see downloading progress in your browser.

Are there any special headers to display progress bar in browser? How I should change my code?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I see nothing special on the site in question in regards to download. There's nothing, header-wise, that you can send in order to make the browser show some sort of nice download progress bar. I think the issue here is your computer more or less, nothing else.

Comment: @N.B.I don't understand why there is a time interval on my site between the moment when you click on the link and see "save file" dialog? I believe something wrong with the code. It looks like browser waits till the moment when WHOLE file will be transmitted before show dialog window.

Comment: I had issues with firefox while I used it, and it downloaded the whole file before notifying me that it's starting. I doubt it's anything to do with headers (it can't be - makes no sense), it's either to your computer (hdd partition full or simply slow/old hdd in question) or firefox's download mechanism (again, no idea about it because I don't use it as much).

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below, and in Firefox it does give me the download time and progress:

```
// send headers first
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$FileName);
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($Path));
// then use an easy way to flush and end all output buffers
while (@ob_end_flush());
// flush file
readfile($Path);
```

It should work if you specify `Content-Length` correctly. The only thing I find mildly weird in your code is the `Content-Type: text/xml` header. Note that I use `Content-type: application/octet-stream`.